# Get contract bytecode and creator from contract address on Geth console

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-debugging, bytecode

I can get contract bytecode and it's creator via this URL.
https://etherscan.io/address/CONTRACT_ADDRESS
[example: https://etherscan.io/address/0x5a3e58c7cf09217d2a5385bf96c02673ed1187bb#code]

I would like to get it on geth console but not found solution during several days.
I think there will be a way since etherscan provide it.
**My try was using web3, but no success, any kind of help will be much appreciate!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytecode should be accessible via `getCode`. I'm not aware of an efficient way to find the contract's creator (the originator of the transaction that created the contract). I believe you would have to just scan transactions.

Comment: Great thanks! I found detailed parameters from this link https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode, hope this help others to reduce time working on ethereum.